# height, min-height not working

Tags: css, height, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make 2 `div`'s inside a container `div` (from Twitter Bootstrap) take the max height which is 100%.
I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sLcZ/7/) to demonstrate, but somehow it's not showing what I want.

Both `div`'s are floated. And therefore I used `class="clearfix"`. But that didn't work either. What am I missing?

**EDIT**
What you don't see in the fiddle, is that `html` and `body` are already set to 100% height in my application.

**EDIT**
The child `div` goes outside it's parent `div`, and that's why it keeps failing.
The jsfiddle has been updated. Anyone can take a look at it?

Comment: In your jsfiddle is wrong border declaration. .boxB has this: `border-color: border: solid 1px red;`.

Comment: You're right, overlooked it. Fixed now.

Comment: Now you still have `border: border: solid 1px red;`. Do you see the mistake? ;)

Comment: Well there are more issues in your fiddle. You're selecting an ID `#wrap` but actually you have to select your class `.wrap`. It would be a great help if you would remove all unnecessary rules in the fiddle.

Comment: That was a quick copy/paste mistake. It's actually an Id. fixed it. And removed some rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a nested block-level element take up 100% height even without any content inside of them, one needs to add `height: 100%;` to the element in question and **all** its parent elements (including html and body). See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2f8ff/).

Giving the divs a height works just fine, but because there is no content inside, the html and body elements don't stretch accordingly.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class=container>
      <div class=stretch-this>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.stretch-this {
  background-color: khaki;
}

html,
body,
.container,
.stretch-this {
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: body and html are set to 100% height. Forgot to mention that. But in my container div, i have 2 divs and both of them have to take 100% height.

Comment: As awkward as it is, throwing `height: 100%;` on them works. You're missing the height declaration on both your .wrap and .container class - atleast in the fiddle. If you add them and test it, it'll work.

Comment: Did what you said and it seems to work. However I have a footer `div` right under the wrap `div` which takes 60px. Now that footer `div` gets 'overflowed' by the wrap `div`. How can I avoid this? jsfiddle updated in my question.

Comment: If you properly clearfix the floated divs or add `clear: both;` to the footer, the footer will be right beneath the divs.

Comment: `clearfix` from TB seems to be always overruled by something. It's striked out. Setting clear: both in the footer css class, didn't work either ;(

Comment: You need to set `clear: both;` on `#footer`, not a class. You've used an ID in your HTML. It works.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Removed the clearfix on both divs and now only set in the footer Id.

Comment: That's definitely not what you're doing. Add `html,body,div{ height: 100%; }` and `#footer { clear: both; }` to your fiddle. If I do this, it works like you would expect it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43179/discussion-between-quoter-and-kleinfreund)